# Unknown error concurring when developing QGIS 2.0.1 plugin in Windows 7

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, python-2.7, gui, attributeerror

I am following the tutorial found [here](http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/plugins_tutorial.html) for developing a simple QGIS plugin within QGIS 2.0.1 installed on Windows 7.  However, as I have began to try developing a link between the GUI and each the mouse click of the map canvas, the main plugin code does not seem to recognize the fields in the GUI.

To illustrate with the example in the tutorial.  Within in my *plugin.py* code I have the function:

```
class vector_selectbypoint:
     def __init__(self, iface):
         # Save reference to the QGIS interface
         self.iface = iface
         # refernce to map canvas
         self.canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
         # out click tool will emit a QgsPoint on every click
         self.clickTool = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(self.canvas)
         # create our GUI dialog
         self.dlg = vector_selectbypointDialog()    

    def handleMouseDown(self, point, button):
         self.dlg.clearTextBrowser()
         self.dlg.setTextBrowser( str(point.x()) + " , " +str(point.y()) )
```

that simply writes the lat and long into a TextBrowser with the GUI by calling the `clearTextBrowser` and `setTextBrowser` functions in a seperate *pluginDialog.py* script where the following code is ran:

```
class vector_selectbypointDialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_vector_selectbypoint):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_vector_selectbypoint()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setTextBrowser(self, output):
        self.ui.txtFeedback.setText(output)

    def clearTextBrowser(self):
        self.ui.txtFeedback.clear()
```

which interacts with the *ui_plugin_ui.py* where `txtFeedback` is the TextBrowser in the GUI.  Below is a snippet of the *ui_plugin_ui.py* file:

```
class Ui_vector_selectbypoint(object):
    def setupUi(self, vector_selectbypoint):
        vector_selectbypoint.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("vector_selectbypoint"))
        vector_selectbypoint.resize(400, 300)
        self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(vector_selectbypoint)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 341, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("buttonBox"))
        self.chkActivate = QtGui.QCheckBox(vector_selectbypoint)
        self.chkActivate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 250, 81, 20))
        self.chkActivate.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("chkActivate"))
        self.txtFeedback = QtGui.QTextBrowser(vector_selectbypoint)
        self.txtFeedback.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 20, 221, 151))
        self.txtFeedback.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("txtFeedback"))
```

The issue is that when I run the plugin in QGIS and click on the map canvas the following error is thrown:

```
AttributeError: 'ui_plugin_ui' object has no attribute 'txtFeedback'
```

I have verified that there are no syntax issues but the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your vector_selectbypoint class inherits from the UI class, get rid of:

```python
self.ui = Ui_vector_selectbypoint()
```

You can then refer to the text browser using:

```python
self.txtFeedback
```

The way your code is now, you are setting self.ui to your UI but never setting it up. That would require using:

```python
self.ui.setupUI(self)
```

rather than

```
self.setupUI(self)
```